# Using np.where with multiple conditions on dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

**I have a Dataframe named volumes containing dates and numbers for thousands of wells.**

```
| WellName | Date     | Oil | Water | Inject |BeforeDate| Before | After | AfterDate
|----------|----------|-----|-------|--------|--------- |--------|-------|----------
| Well_1   | 1/1/2000 | 10  | 10    |        | 1/1/2001 | Prod   |  Inj  | 1/1/2002
| Well_1   | 1/1/2001 | 10  | 20    |        | 1/1/2001 | Prod   |  Inj  | 1/1/2002
| Well_1   | 1/1/2002 | 50  | 60    |        | 1/1/2001 | Prod   |  Inj  | 1/1/2002
| Well_2   | 1/1/2000 |     |       | 700    | 1/1/2001 | Inj    |  Prod | 1/1/2002
| Well_2   | 1/1/2001 |     |       | 720    | 1/1/2001 | Inj    |  Prod | 1/1/2002
| Well_2   | 1/1/2002 |     |       | 800    | 1/1/2001 | Inj    |  Prod | 1/1/2002
| Well_3   | 1/1/2000 |     |       | 1000   | 1/1/2001 | Inj    |  Inj  | 1/1/2002
| Well_3   | 1/1/2001 |     |       | 1500   | 1/1/2001 | Inj    |  Inj  | 1/1/2002
| Well_3   | 1/1/2002 |     |       | 2000   | 1/1/2001 | Inj    |  Inj  | 1/1/2002
```

I need to sum the Oil + Water columns by year for wells where the Date is <= BeforeDate & Before == 'Prod', else I want to sum the Inject column where Date <= BeforeDate & Before == 'Inj'.

How do I include the Else Date <= BeforeDate & Before == 'Inj' ?

This is what I've gotten to so far and realize it is incorrect.

```
volumes['totals_before'] = np.where((volumes['Before'] == 'Prod') & (volumes['Date'] <= volumes['BeforeDate']), volumes['Oil'] + volumes['Water'], volumes['Inject'])
```

**Once volumes['totals_before'] calculates correctly, I will need to forward fill (ffill) the most recent sum (1/1/2001 in this case) and add it to another column, volumes['totals_after'] which is Date >= AfterDate.**

The end result would look something like this:

```
volumes['new_Tots'] = volumes['totals_before'] + volumes['totals_after']
```

**Expected Output:**

```
| WellName |   Date   | totals_before | totals_after | new_Tots |
|----------|----------|---------------|--------------|----------|
| Well_1   | 1/1/2000 |      20       |              |   20     |
| Well_1   | 1/1/2001 |      30       |              |   30     |
| Well_1   | 1/1/2002 |  30(ffill)    |     110      |   140    |
| Well_2   | 1/1/2000 |      700      |              |   700    |
| Well_2   | 1/1/2001 |      720      |              |   720    |
| Well_2   | 1/1/2002 |  720(ffill)   |     800      |   1520   |
| Well_3   | 1/1/2000 |      1000     |              |   1000   |
| Well_3   | 1/1/2001 |      1500     |              |   1500   |
| Well_3   | 1/1/2002 |  1500(ffill)  |     2000     |   3500   |
```

Comment: show us your expected out put

Comment: I changed some values in the raw data table to make it easier to read. I've also included expected output.

Comment: Can you have a different data format? Use `to_dict` to give dictionary of the dataframe.

Comment: Can there be a situation where you have more than one row per year per well?

Comment: Does `Before` column only have `prod` and `inj`?

Comment: @Tai The dataframe is populated by a .read_sql statement and there's quite a few other calculations taking place in the dataframe beyond this one. The before column only contains the strings, 'prod' or 'inj'.

Comment: @Prikers Yes, the data is monthly, but to make it easier to read I summarized into years. The before and after columns determine whether you sum production or injection because a well can change types over the years.

Comment: @Quasar can you provide data with `to_dict()` to your data frame? like `df.to_dict()` It is a whole lot of preprocessing before I can work on you real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Think this should work.

```
Prod_part = volumes.where(volumes.Date <= volumes.BeforeDate)\
                   .where(volumes.Before == "Prod")[["Water", "Oil"]].sum(
                          axis=1, min_count=1)
Inj_part = volumes.where(volumes.Date <= volumes.BeforeDate).where(volumes.Before == "Inj")["Inject"]

volumes["totals_before"] = Inj_part.combine_first(Prod_part)
volumes.totals_before.ffill(inplace=True)


0      20.0
1      30.0
2      30.0
3     700.0
4     720.0
5     720.0
6    1000.0
7    1500.0
8    1500.0
```

Again, give your dataframe using `to_dict` function to save our life.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit verbose but may serve as a nice draft to what you are trying to achieve. It assumes that dates can be compared (so they are stored as `datetime` not as strings).

```
condition = volumes['Date'] <= volumes['BeforeDate']

# Before
volumes.loc[(condition) & (volumes['Before'] == 'Prod'),
            'totals_before'] = volumes['Oil'] + volumes['Water']
volumes.loc[(condition) & (volumes['Before'] == 'Inj'),
            'totals_before'] = volumes['Inject']

# After
volumes.loc[(~condition) & (volumes['Before'] == 'Prod'),
            'totals_after'] = volumes['Oil'] + volumes['Water']
volumes.loc[(~condition) & (volumes['Before'] == 'Inj'),
            'totals_after'] = volumes['Inject']

volumes = volumes.sort_values(by=['WellName', 'Date'])
volumes['totals_before'] = volumes['totals_before'].fillna(method='ffill')

volumes['new_Tots'] = volumes['totals_before'] + volumes['totals_after'].fillna(0)
```

Which outputs:

```
In[3]: volumes[['WellName', 'Date', 'totals_before', 'totals_after', 'new_Tots']]
Out[3]: 
     WellName       Date  totals_before  totals_after  new_Tots
0   Well_1    2000-01-01           20.0           NaN      20.0
1   Well_1    2001-01-01           30.0           NaN      30.0
2   Well_1    2002-01-01           30.0         110.0     140.0
3   Well_2    2000-01-01          700.0           NaN     700.0
4   Well_2    2001-01-01          720.0           NaN     720.0
5   Well_2    2002-01-01          720.0         800.0    1520.0
6   Well_3    2000-01-01         1000.0           NaN    1000.0
7   Well_3    2001-01-01         1500.0           NaN    1500.0
8   Well_3    2002-01-01         1500.0        2000.0    3500.0
```

This can be greatly simplified if the following assumption is correct: columns Oil and Water are always empty when Inject is populated and vice-versa.

Comment: I have taken more time to reflect on this and think that populating 'totals_before' with the value of the 'oil' column where Date == BeforeDate is the way to get this into production fastest.


In the example above, Well_1 would forward fill the value of 10, Well_2 would forward fill the value of 800 if it were under the 'Oil' column and so on. 


I'm unsure of how to filter in that regard when you are grouping by WellName.